# JBOSS EAP6.2 says java.lang.ClassNotFoundException but there is that class into lib folder

Tags: java, spring, jboss, aspectj

I have a problem with lib aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar, necessary for Spring AOP, when i try to deploy on Jboss Eap6.2. I added this dependency on my pom:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I found aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar on my WEB-INF\lib folder into WAR but Jboss give me java.lang.ClassNotFoundException because it searchs the lib into my custom module. I can't add that lib in that module. What can i do?

```
18:37:23,257 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 240) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-web.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:628) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:470) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getPointcut(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:192) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisor(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:178) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisors(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:108) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:109) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:87) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:289) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:465) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException from [Module "com.foo.abc:main" from local module loader @9f14c3 (finder: local module finder @c282b (roots: C:\Program Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,C:\Program Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: If i add aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar to custom module all work, but i'm not the owner :-(

Answer (score 1):

The exception thrown by JBoss is not ClassNotFoundException. Instead it is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. This means that there are more than one class definition in your classpath.

So you have to tell JBoss which one to use. And you do that using custom modules.

You can see more here
[Creating module in jBoss AS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925266/creating-module-in-jboss-as)

Comment: Thanks for answer Reos but I don't know how resolve the problem. Are you sure there are more than one ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException.class? because I can't found it and the last 'Caused by' is ClassNotFoundException . How can I tell to Jboss to use the class into web-inf\lib?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that: in my applicaton there are two different class loader,

- one for my class and lib inside .war file
- one for the lib inside the module.

The module class loader don't see the lib inside the war and vice-versa. The solution was to put all lib linked by dependency, in the same place (module or war lib folder)